# How do you mount an sql dump in a Laravel project working locally?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

hope you are doing well, I am looking for debugging an `internal server error 500` in a Laravel project, so I did an SQL dump from the remote servor and I would like to test this dump locally.

I have got the error in the remote but not in my localhost so I am trying to reproduce it locally.

How could I insert this SQL dump in my local project using Laravel 5, is there a `php artisan` command to run it or may I create a php function to insert it?

My dump is actually on my local machine and he is name `Dump20171204.sql`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a third-party application like `MySQL Workbench` to import your dumb to your database.

Comment: @Chin Leung thanks for the help I will let you know tomorrow If I can get it working with your solution